# Browse the file hierarchy of directory containing an index file

Tags: html, file, indexing, directory, hierarchy

If I navigate to a public directory on a web site with no index file in it I see the file hierarchy for that directory displayed in the browser window. If that public directory contains an index file I instead see the index file displayed. Is there any way to browse the file hierarchy of directory containing an index file?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not possible to view the directory structure when a default file exists.

Most web servers will first display the default file and if it does not exist and the server is configured to display directories, display the folder structure as HTML.